# How to search for A (any lengths any character) * in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string

I have a string with letters and occasionally *. I am trying to write regular expressions in Python 3 to get anything in the string that starts with A and ends with *, things in between can be any letter but not *. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: How about testing `r"(A.+?\*)"`

Comment: @JonSG, regular expressions are eager by default, which means that they try to capture the longest match. Your regex will capture the substring starting at the first `A` and ending at the last `*`. I suggest this regex: `A[^*]*\*`

Comment: @NirH. You are mistaken. Try it yourself `print(re.search(r"(A.+?\*)", "This is Atest* but not this*").group(0))`

Comment: @JonSG, sorry, I missed the `?` after the `+`, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the regex pattern `\bA\w*\*(?!\S)`:

```py
inp = "An example is an A* and also an Abc*"
matches = re.findall(r'\bA\w*\*(?!\S)', inp)
print(matches)  # ['A*', 'Abc*']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler pattern one can use with python regex.

`r"(A.+?\*)"`

For more on "Greedy vs Non-Greedy in Python": https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy

An example:

```
import re
string_to_test = "This is Atest1* but not this* but Atest2* done *a asdf"
for x in re.findall(r"(A.+?\*)", string_to_test):
    print(x)
```

This will produce:

```
Atest1*
Atest2*
```

Note that depending on if the string "A*" is valid or not you might need the pattern `r"(A.*?\*)"`

Comment: Thanks JonSG! r"(A.+?\*)" worked for me. I will study the link you sent- it seems to contain all the information for regex.